# Is it a good style to run external commands in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have lots of external shell commands to run.

So I gave every command a name and then run it.

```
tar_report_cmd = 'zip -r  {0} {1} '%(report_file, _export_dir)
exec_proc(tar_report_cmd)
mv_report_cmd = "mv {0} {1}".format(report_file,report_dir)
exec_proc(mv_report_cmd)
```

But it looks sort of redundant and not beautiful.

Is there any better practice to replace my way?

```
def exec_proc(cmd_str):
    results = os.popen(cmd_str).read()
    return results
```

Comment: For the examples given, I would suggest using the library support for zip files and moving files. It's more cross-platform and gives you better precision and error recovery options. Tend towards calling other commands only when library versions are unavailable and do exactly what you need.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is primarily about how to write code, rather than really reviewing code that has been written.

Comment: @MichaelUrman The code may be written at a novice level, but it's still reviewable code. We're all here to learn how to write better code, and this question is no different.

Comment: @MichaelUrman Also, your comment that this should be done using a Python library rather than an external command [should be posted as an answer](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1479/9357), since it is a suggestion that would result in an improvement.

Comment: @200_success I agree that if it were an on-topic question, my comment should be posted as an answer. But I see this as  asking if it's a good approach, rather than asking for a code review. Note that the code given doesn't even work (what's `report_file`, `_export_dir`, ...?).

Answer (score 5):

**No, it is a security risk**, and furthermore, `os.popen()` has been [deprecated](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#file-object-creation) since Python 2.6.  The replacement is to use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3).

The security risk is that `os.popen()` expects its command as a string.  That means that the command will be interpreted by a shell to split it up into the command and its arguments.  If `report_file`, `report_dir`, or `_export_dir` contain any spaces or characters with a special meaning to the shell, horrible unexpected things can happen, including **arbitrary command execution**.